# Как запретить обновления данных в WPF в TextBox?

Tags: c#, wpf

У меня есть метод во ViewModel который обновляет данные каждую секунду с базы, получается когда я хочу изменить данные в TexBox данные которые я ввожу перебиваются каждую секунду, как запретить обновлять данные когда TexBox находится в фокусе??

Comment: А за что минус? Валидный вопрос между прочим.

Comment: @VladD за то, что вопрос в виде потока сознания, кмк

Comment: @Ivan Prodaiko По умолчанию у TextBox режим для обновления свойства - LostFocus...

Comment: @Ev_Hyper: Не, тут вопрос в другую сторону: обновление при фокусе должно быть заблокировано не в сторону из V к VM, а из VM к V.

Comment: @VladD мм, скорее всего вы правы, хотя из формулироки это не очевидно

Comment: Подпишитесь не биндингом, а из code-behind напрямую к INPC и флажок сделайте там же. А сам флажок переключайте по событию фокус

Comment: @IvanProdaiko, @VladD, Менять привязку, например, на `OneWayToSource` у меня получилось с помощью триггера, но это получается бессмысленно. Скорее всего вам нужно при постановке фокуса в `TextBox` посылать команду для постановки метода загрузки на паузу, а когда курсор уходит - как-то обрабатывать это значение и запускать метод загрузки... В общем логика как-то хромает... %)

Comment: А что нужно сделать, если (1) текстбокс получил фокус, (2) тем временем значение VM-свойства поменялось, (3) юзер ничего не напечатал и убрал фокус?

Comment: @VladD +1, хороший вопрос. Посмотрите моё решение, я сделал так: при получении фокуса текстбоксом привязка продолжает обновляться(ровно так же как и без фокуса), затем как только юзер начинает печатать она отключается и включается тогда, когда юзер уберёт фокус. При этом значение свойства изменяется на введенное и обновления само собой продолжаются далее.

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATE**: Более гибкое решение с использованием Behaviors:

```
public class TextBoxBehavior : Behavior<TextBox>
{
    private readonly DependencyProperty _targetProperty = TextBox.TextProperty;

    private BindingExpression _bindingExpression;
    private DateTime _keyDownRaisedAt;
    private bool _bindingCleared;

    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        base.OnAttached();

        _bindingExpression = AssociatedObject.GetBindingExpression(_targetProperty);

        AssociatedObject.LostFocus += AssociatedObjectOnLostFocus;
        AssociatedObject.PreviewTextInput += AssociatedObjectOnPreviewTextInput;
        AssociatedObject.PreviewKeyDown += AssociatedObjectOnPreviewKeyDown;

    }

    private void AssociatedObjectOnPreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs keyEventArgs)
    {
        _keyDownRaisedAt = DateTime.Now;
    }

    private void AssociatedObjectOnLostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
    {    
        if (_bindingCleared && _bindingExpression != null)
        {
            string tmp = AssociatedObject.Text;
            AssociatedObject.SetBinding(_targetProperty, _bindingExpression.ParentBinding);
            _bindingCleared = false;
            AssociatedObject.SetCurrentValue(_targetProperty, tmp);
        }
    }

    private void AssociatedObjectOnPreviewTextInput(object sender, TextCompositionEventArgs textCompositionEventArgs)
    {
        if (!_bindingCleared && AssociatedObject.IsFocused && IsKeyDown())
        {
            BindingOperations.ClearBinding(AssociatedObject, _targetProperty);
            _bindingCleared = true;
        }
    }

    private bool IsKeyDown()
    {
        DateTime currentTime = DateTime.Now;
        return (currentTime - _keyDownRaisedAt) < TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(10);
    }

    protected override void OnDetaching()
    {
        base.OnDetaching();

        AssociatedObject.PreviewTextInput -= AssociatedObjectOnPreviewTextInput;
        AssociatedObject.PreviewKeyDown -= AssociatedObjectOnPreviewKeyDown;
        AssociatedObject.LostFocus -= AssociatedObjectOnLostFocus;

    }
}
```

Для его подключения в XAML-разметке необходимо написать:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Text, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
    <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <Behaviors:TextBoxBehavior />
    </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
</TextBox>
```

И не забыть так же соответствующее пространство имён:

```
xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
```

---

Решение с кастомным TextBox:

```
public class CustomTextBox : TextBox
{
    private DateTime _keyDownRaisedAt;
    private BindingExpression _binding;
    private bool _bindingCleared;

    protected override void OnPreviewKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        _keyDownRaisedAt = DateTime.Now;
        base.OnPreviewKeyDown(e);
    }

    public override void EndInit()
    {
        _binding = this.GetBindingExpression(TextProperty);
        base.EndInit();
    }


    protected override void OnLostFocus(RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (_bindingCleared)
        {
            var tmp = this.Text;
            SetBinding(TextProperty, _binding.ParentBinding);
            _bindingCleared = false;
            SetCurrentValue(TextProperty, tmp);
        }
        base.OnLostFocus(e);
    }

    protected override void OnPreviewTextInput(TextCompositionEventArgs e)
    {
        DateTime current = DateTime.Now;

        if (!_bindingCleared && IsFocused && (current - _keyDownRaisedAt) < TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(10))
        {
            BindingOperations.ClearBinding(this, TextProperty);
            _bindingCleared = true;
        }
        base.OnPreviewTextInput(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: А можно небольшой комментарий по поводу работы с `Binding`? `GetBindingExpression` и `ParentBinding` для меня, например, крайняя экзотика.

Answer (score 2):

Я пойду по пути постановки таймера на паузу, другой вариант мне кажется алогичным. У меня работает такой простой пример:

Доменная модель данных из БД (у вас она есть своя):

```
class UserModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Набросок репозитория для получения экземпляров `UserModel`:

```
class UserRepository
{
    List<UserModel> users;

    public UserRepository()
    {
        users = new List<UserModel>
        {
            new UserModel { Id = 1, Name = "Иванов Иван" },
            new UserModel { Id = 2, Name = "Петров Петр" },
            new UserModel { Id = 3, Name = "Сидоров Сидор" },
            new UserModel { Id = 4, Name = "Антонов Антон" },
            new UserModel { Id = 5, Name = "Сергеев Сергей" }
        };
    }

    public UserModel GetUserByIndex(int index) => users[index];
    public UserModel GetUserById(int id) => users.First(u => u.Id == id);

    public int UsersCount => users.Count;
}
```

"Стандартные" (немного упрощенные) вспомогательные классы для `MVVM`, честно собранные на просторах SO/ruSO:

База для `VM`:

```
class VM : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    protected void Set<T>(ref T field, T value, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
    {
        field = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged(propertyName);
    }

    protected void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "") =>
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

Реализация `ICommand`:

```
class DelegateCommand : ICommand
{
    Action<object> execute;
    Predicate<object> canExecute = _ => true;

    public DelegateCommand(Action<object> execute)
    {
        if (execute == null) throw new NullReferenceException(nameof(execute));
        this.execute = execute;
    }

    public DelegateCommand(Action<object> execute, Predicate<object> canExecute)
        : this(execute)
    {
        if (canExecute == null) throw new NullReferenceException(nameof(canExecute));
        this.canExecute = canExecute;
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter) => canExecute(parameter);

    public void Execute(object parameter) => execute(parameter);
}
```

Основная `VM`:

```
class MainVM : VM
{
    UserRepository repo = new UserRepository();

    UserModel selectedUser;
    public UserModel SelectedUser
    {
        get { return selectedUser; }
        set { Set(ref selectedUser, value); }
    }

    DelegateCommand pauseCommand;
    public ICommand PauseCommand
    {
        get
        {
            if (pauseCommand == null)
                pauseCommand = new DelegateCommand(_ => PauseTimer());
            return pauseCommand;
        }
    }

    DelegateCommand playCommand;
    public ICommand PlayCommand
    {
        get
        {
            if (playCommand == null)
                playCommand = new DelegateCommand(_ => StartTimer());
            return playCommand;
        }
    }

    Timer timer = new Timer(1000);
    int currentIndex = -1;

    public MainVM()
    {
        timer.Elapsed += (o, e) => NextUser();
        timer.Start();
    }

    void NextUser()
    {
        currentIndex = (currentIndex + 1) % repo.UsersCount;
        SelectedUser = repo.GetUserByIndex(currentIndex);
    }

    void PauseTimer()
    {
        timer.Stop();
    }

    void StartTimer()
    {
        // Здесь надо обновить запись в БД:
        // repo.UpdateUser(SelectedUser);
        timer.Start();
    }
}
```

Разметка содержимого окна:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <TextBlock Margin="5,5,0,5" VerticalAlignment="Center"
               Text="{Binding SelectedUser.Id}"/>

    <TextBox Grid.Column="1"
             Margin="5" Padding="5"
             Text="{Binding SelectedUser.Name}">
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="GotFocus">
                <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding PauseCommand}"/>
            </i:EventTrigger>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="LostFocus">
                <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding PlayCommand}"/>
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    </TextBox>

    <Button Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="1"
            Margin="5" Padding="5"
            VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Center"
            Content="Click Me"/>
</Grid>
```

Здесь используется пространство имен `xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"`, не забудьте подключить `NuGet`-пакет `System.Windows.Interactivity`

Выглядит всё вот так:

[image: Скриншот]

Comment: System.Windows.Interactivity вроде бы сейчас в стандартной поставке (Visual Studio 2017)

Comment: @VladD, на работе стоит 2015, поэтому некоторые фишки недоступны. В 2017 дома не проверял.

Answer (score 2):

Ещё одно решение по мотивам идеи с attached behaviour, которую продемонстрировал @Nikita.

```
public class NondisruptiveUpdateBehavior : Behavior<TextBox>
{
    readonly Binding binding;

    public NondisruptiveUpdateBehavior()
    {
        binding = new Binding(TextProperty.Name) { Source = this };
    }

    // dependency property, которое будет прикреплено к источнику
    public string Text
    {
        get => (string)GetValue(TextProperty);
        set => SetValue(TextProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
            "Text", typeof(string), typeof(NondisruptiveUpdateBehavior),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(
                    null, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault));

    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        base.OnAttached();
        // подпишемся на изменение фокуса
        AssociatedObject.GotFocus += OnGotFocus;
        AssociatedObject.LostFocus += OnLostFocus;
        // если фокуса нет, установим привязку
        if (!AssociatedObject.IsFocused)
            Setup(false);
    }

    protected override void OnDetaching()
    {
        // если фокуса нет, уберём привязку
        if (!AssociatedObject.IsFocused)
            OnGotFocus(null, null);
        // и отпишемся от изменений фокуса
        AssociatedObject.LostFocus -= OnLostFocus;
        AssociatedObject.GotFocus -= OnGotFocus;
        base.OnDetaching();
    }

    void OnGotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) => Clear();
    void OnLostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) => Setup(true);

    void Clear()
    {
        string tmp = AssociatedObject.Text;
        // убрать привязку тексбокса к нашему свойству
        BindingOperations.ClearBinding(AssociatedObject, TextBox.TextProperty);
        // передать значение вверх
        AssociatedObject.Text = tmp;
    }

    void Setup(bool propagate)
    {
        string tmp = AssociatedObject.Text;
        // установить привязку тексбокса к нашему свойству
        BindingOperations.SetBinding(AssociatedObject, TextBox.TextProperty, binding);
        if (propagate)
        {
            // передать значение вниз
            SetCurrentValue(TextProperty, tmp);
            var expr = BindingOperations.GetBindingExpression(this, TextProperty);
            expr?.UpdateTarget(); // если нет привязки вниз, то и не нужно
        }
    }
}
```

Пользоваться так:

```
<TextBox xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity">
    <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <local:NondisruptiveUpdateBehavior Text="{Binding Value}"/>
    </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
</TextBox>
```

Не забудьте подключить сборку System.Windows.Interactivity.

Результат:

[image: анимашка]

Comment: Отличное решение!

Comment: @Nikita: Спасибо! Заодно выучил и попробовал что-то новое :-)